# Removing sort icons from Excel table

Tags: excel

Elsewhere in these discussions I found how to remove the sort icons fron an Excel table. Unfortunately, the instructions are too cryptic for a person of my age (nearer to 60 than I am to 50):

1. Select the data range
2. Format as table
3. Right click --> Select Table --> Convert to Range

I got as far as #2, but my data was already in a table, so I ignored this.

Then I come to "Right Click"... I did, all over nearly every pixel on my  desktop, but nowhere encountered "Select Table".

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: May you please post a link to the address that has described the solution?

Answer (score 1):

You should do the following:
1. Select your entire table > From INSERT Menu click on Table and then OK. Now you created a table
2. Select the entire table > Right click in any cell of your table > click on Table > click on Convert to Range and then click on OK. Now you have a table without sort icons in the header.

Answer (score 0):

Normally sort icons appear when you filter the data, you can just go to the "Data" Menu and unselect the filter button.

[image: Excel filtering menu]

You can find good step by step explanations on filtering directly from microsoft in:

https://support.office.com/en-US/article/Sort-data-in-a-range-or-table-62d0b95d-2a90-4610-a6ae-2e545c4a4654?omkt=en-US

Hope it helps!